# Executing operations in Background in Windows Store apps

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I am building up an universal app targeting 8.1 runtime and also new to whole .NET world.

I have some operations  in my application which I want to perform in parallel, asynchronously and also in background. These operations include file upload, download (both I/O and compute bound). So I wanted to execute them In threads.  I would like to process them in 3 threads. Each thread will work on the operation queue and keep waiting perpetually (in while(true) loop) unless an operation is available for execution. These threads would also pass task status or progress updates to UI.

Would also like to have these threads running on Application lock or if the app suspends . If my application terminates or if the network connections is lost these threads will stop. Also would like to cancel the operations running in the threads according to me requirements (like cancelling a file download).

My initial hunch was to use threads. But since threads are not available for windows store apps and my exploration about threading in Windows store apps revealed to use task to perform this.

I read about the Tasks Asynchrony pattern (TAP) whitepaper published by MS ,channel 9 videos from Bruce Kyle and lot of other blogs. I am convinced to use Tasks .As it runs on a thread pool which can take advantage  of multi core processor and is better performing

Questions on Tasks will be

1. Will it be useful as background thread. Can tasks be run as a
   background thread perpetually.
2. I don't really need my tasks to return results. The result from the
   operations can be relayed to UI through events.
3. Do I have to schedule my tasks from a background task API when the
   app suspend ?

Does the Task API fit my scenario ?
Are Background tasks in Windows same as services in Android.  ?

Thanks a lot and Regards,

Saurav

Answer (score 1):

Note that file uploads and downloads *already* happen on background threads in Windows Store apps, so you don't really need to worry about it impacting your UI at all. If you want to do computationally-expensive work also, I would just spin off a new `Task` whenever you want to do something asynchronously unless you have specific needs around a dedicated thread reading from a queue.

If you must a perpetual thread, **do not** run a busy loop waiting for work; use a signalable object like an [`AutoResetEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(v=vs.110).aspx)instead) to wake it up when there is something to do. This will minimize wasted CPU power (and hence battery).

Background execution is limited in Windows Store apps; you can read about it [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh977056(v=win.10).aspx).

Comment: thanks a lot Peter for your reply. Just to illustrate more i don't want my UI to directly interact with the threads/tasks. I would just fire events from UI to trigger the operations in the perpetual running threads. I agree with AutoResetEvent that it would be better.

Comment: Is there a reason you want the dedicated threads? Perhaps that is the easiest conceptual model based on other platforms but I think you can get away without it unless you have some unspecified constraints.

Comment: One scenario in my case will be spawning off multiple tasks..probably have to filter off the tasks before scheduling them...having some dedicated threads will do that for me..will be able to control the execution of operations